# In what data science applications has the stack exchange dump been used?

Tags: dataset, social-network-analysis, information-retrieval

Anonymized dumps of the stack exchange data are [available here](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange). Do you know projects or article that have been using these data (for social network analysis or information retrieval) ? My little research on the subject on Google Scholar & co seems to indicate that this dataset has been very seldom used.

Comment: I think it is borderline whether this can be answered well. Individuals answering it would have to do an unreasonable amount of research IMO. However, unlike a a shopping question or "what's the best Foo for Bar",  I think it is possible for there to be a long-lasting and useful answer. Hence I have started a Community Wiki answer.

Comment: SO's data blog contains some good projects by the in-house data science folks.  Not sure if it is the from the dump or not :D

Comment: @debzsud have you seen anything yourself? I searched a lot but just saw the link of the answer that has been provided. I guess projects using that will be so much great.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Community Wiki answer, everyone is welcome to add references.

- Kaggle ran a competition to predict whether a question would be closed on Stack Overflow: https://www.kaggle.com/c/predict-closed-questions-on-stack-overflow